# Kotlin if statement fails

Tags: android, kotlin

I have following if statement but it always fails to show correct data

```
if(!currentItem.address.toString().isNullOrEmpty() && !useraddress.isNullOrEmpty()) {
  holder.distanceca.isVisible = true
} else {
  holder.distanceca.isVisible = false
}
```

`Explanation`

Based on my sample data `useraddress` is `null` so it suppose to fall into `holder.distanceca.isVisible = false` but instead it's returning `holder.distanceca.isVisible = true`

PS: for my purpose of running `holder.distanceca.isVisible = true` both `currentItem.address` and `useraddress` must have values if any of them is `empty` or `null` it should hide the element.

**Any idea how to properly make if statement in kotlin?**

Comment: You do not call `toString()` on a null object . just change it to `if(!currentItem.address.isNullOrEmpty() && !useraddress.isNullOrEmpty())` . It not about kotlin its just basic control statement .

Comment: same result still getting `holder.distanceca.isVisible = true`

Comment: Try `if (currentItem.address.length > 0 && useraddress.length > 0)`

Comment: @whyp still same issue

Answer (score 1):

#### Solved

`Working code`

```
if(!currentItem.address.isNullOrEmpty() && !useraddress.isNullOrEmpty()) {
  val geoCoder = Geocoder(context)
  // laundry location
  val arrs1 = geoCoder.getFromLocationName(currentItem.address, 1)
  if (arrs1?.isNotEmpty() == true) {
    address = arrs1[0]
  }
  // customer location
  val arrs = geoCoder.getFromLocationName(useraddress, 1)
  if (arrs?.isNotEmpty() == true) {
    usera = arrs[0]
  }

  if (arrs1?.isNotEmpty() == true && arrs?.isNotEmpty() == true) {
    holder.distanceca.isVisible = true
    val locationA = Location(currentItem.name)
    locationA.latitude = address?.latitude ?: 0.0
    locationA.longitude = address?.longitude ?: 0.0
    val locationB = Location("You")
    locationB.latitude = usera?.latitude ?: 0.0
    locationB.longitude = usera?.longitude ?: 0.0

    val distance = DecimalFormat("##.##").format(locationA.distanceTo(locationB) / 1000)
    holder.distanceca.text = "${distance} KM"
  } else {
    holder.distanceca.isVisible = false
  }
}
```

I've add extra if condition to my code and that fixed it somehow (honestly, I am not sure why is that myself :D )

```
if (arrs1?.isNotEmpty() == true && arrs?.isNotEmpty() == true) {
  //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
if(!currentItem.address.toString().isNullOrEmpty()) {
  useraddress?.let{
    if (!it.isNullOrEmpty())
      holder.distanceca.isVisible = true
    else
      holder.distanceca.isVisible = false   
  }?.let{
    holder.distanceca.isVisible = false
  }
}
```